# Bundle product: Add to cart instead of select option

Tags: magento-1, addtocart, bundled-product

I want to add **add to cart** on product detail page instead of select option, how can it be done?

As of now it shows select option on product detail page , but i want add to cart button that will just add item to cart with all available options

Please guide me way to do this.

Will adding below code work?

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to configure the bundle so that there is only one possible combination:

Fore each single item, create a separate option with only one selection. Choose the type "checkbox" and make it "required".

Then no "select options" shows up and the customer can add the product directly to the cart.